# NetBeans java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory] at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:171)

Tags: java, netbeans, xml-parsing

I have updated NetBeans to version 12. My Application was created in Java 8. I use now java 14. All is running but this:

```
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:171)
```

I raead many posts in Google but i can’t hit a solution.
This error occurs only if i run in NetBeans app. If i compile my app and run it it works without errors.

I habe also downloaded jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar and added to library.
Edit: Alos tryed jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar. No success.

But realy crasy is, if i run my app in Terminal i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXB
```

Only on click on myApp.jar in my current folder it runs without any error:

Has any body an idea?
What is a solution for this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
For now i found a solution but whith this WARNING:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache%20NetBeans%2012.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/ide/modules/ext/jaxb/jaxb-impl.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

this appears if i use this JAXB 2.2.5.jar library.
Don’t work wit JAXB versions as described above.

My app runs now with 2.2.5 but how long?

Sorry but i have no idea how i can inform the developer. i.g. Sun or Marven or whoever. I true this issue is known there. But i’s bad that it isn’t fixt yet. :(

This ist my code:

```
package Tools;

import Enums.Property;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static Tools.Device.Director;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


    @XmlRootElement
    public class Device {
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return DeviceName;
        }
    
        /**
         *
         */
        public static final String Separator = FileHandler.getFileSeparator();
        public static File Director = new File(Property.datarefBaseFile.getValue().substring(0, Property.datarefBaseFile.getValue().lastIndexOf(Separator)) + Separator + "Devices" + Separator);
    
        @XmlElement
        public String DeviceName;
        @XmlElement
        public String DevicePosX;
        @XmlElement
        public String DevicePosY;
        @XmlElement
        public String DeviceWidth;
        @XmlElement
        public String DeviceHeight;
        @XmlElement
        public String DeviceBackgroundImage;
        @XmlElement
        public String DeviceScaleX;
        @XmlElement
        public String DeviceScaleY;
    
        public List<ControlProps> controlsProps;
    
        public static Device load(String file) {
            return JAXB.unmarshal(new File(Director, file), Device.class);
        }
    
        public static File getDirector() {
            return Director;
        }
    
        public void save() {
            Director.mkdir();
            File file = new File(Director, DeviceName + ".xml");
            File fileback = new File(Director, DeviceName + ".bak");
    
            if (fileback.exists()) {
                fileback.delete();
                System.out.println(String.format("Device %s old deleted! %s", fileback, Utils.ShowTime()));
            }
            file.renameTo(fileback);
    
            if (fileback.exists()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Device %s new created! %s", fileback, Utils.ShowTime()));
            }
    
            if (!file.exists()) {
                JAXB.marshal(this, file);
                String msg = String.format("Device %s saved! %s", file, Utils.ShowTime());
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
    
            if (!file.exists()) {
                String msg = String.format("Fatal error: %s was deleted an not created new!\nDevice crashed.\nRestore from %s file. %s", file, fileback, Utils.ShowTime());
                System.out.println(msg);
                MsgBox.error(msg);
            }
    
            if (!fileback.exists()) {
                String msg = String.format("Warning! Backupfile: %s was not created yet! %s", fileback, Utils.ShowTime());
                System.out.println(msg);
                MsgBox.error(msg);
            }
            //       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
            //       LogFile.log(Level.INFO, new String[] {file.toString() + " saved"});
        }
    
        public int delete() {
            File fileBak = new File(Director, DeviceName + ".creater.bak");
            File file = new File(Director, DeviceName + ".xml");
            int response = 0;
            String msg = String.format("Delete this device: %s?", DeviceName);
            response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, msg, "Confirm",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION && file.exists()) {
                file.renameTo(fileBak);
                file.delete();
                msg = String.format("File: %s deleted\nBackupfile %s was created!", file, fileBak);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
            } else {
                msg = String.format("%s not deleted file: %s", DeviceName, file);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
            }
    
            return response;
        }
    
        public Device() {
            controlsProps = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    
        public ControlProps find(String name) {
            for (ControlProps prop : controlsProps) {
    
                if (prop.ControlName.equals(name)) {
                    return prop;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ControlName not found");
        }
    
        public void deleteControl(ControlProps controlProps) {
            String name = controlProps.ControlName;
            if (controlsProps.remove(controlProps)) {
                save();
                System.out.println(name + " deleted");
                //LogFile.log(Level.INFO, new String[]{name + " deleted"});
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: [1] Are you using annotations in your code to unmarshall? If not see [Unmarshal without jaxb annotations](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/unmarshal-without-xmlrootelement/). [2] If that isn't relevant, or doesn't help, update your question to show your code that causes the problem. If the code is complex create a [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have edit my post with my code. hope it helps to understand my problem.